# How do I add a GTM event to a callback triggered upon this form completion?

Tags: forms, callback, global-variables, google-tag-manager, addeventlistener

I am setting up GTM Event Tracking and Facebook Pixel tracking for a client.

They are using a CRM system with a form widget which is embedded on the website via Javascript. As such, there is no direct way of tracking the form.

Their developers have asked me to use their global variables, one of which allows me to add in a callback which is triggered upon 'formCompleted'.

Please see the code below. The last variable allows me to input a callback, but honestly speaking, I have no idea how to make it fire an event to Google Tag Manager, or Facebook Pixel.

```
var intouchFormConfig = {
includeCss: true, //s et false to stop the default stylesheet from being loaded
foregroundColour: null, //set to a css colour - e.g. #fff- to override what is
configured on the server
matterGuid: null, // Id of a matter. If this is set the matter will be updated with
the results of this form
bannerUrl: null, //a n image to display at the top of the form
autoActivate: true,//by default the widget will automatically activate,
events: {
activa ted: () => {}, //an optional callback triggered once the widget is
activated
formCompleted: (response) => {}, //an optional callback triggered once a form
inside the widget has been completed by the user
},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The general concept to generate custom events in Google Tag Manager (GTM) is to push the `event` variable into dataLayer of GTM. You can set up Custom Event triggers in GTM to launch any tags, that are relevant to this event. You need to provide the name of the event as `Event name` in the trigger settings.

The general syntax for this is:

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: 'myEventName'
});
```

In your case, you need to provide a function, that will make this call. You can also pass the response to GTM as a dataLayer variable, if you need to use it in connection to your event. (E.g. check for success, failure, or any other outcome.) So your code should look something like this:

```
var intouchFormConfig = {
  //your other configuration items

  //events part
  events: {
    activated: () => {},
    formCompleted: (response) => {
      dataLayer.push({
        event : 'intouchFormCompleted',  //an event name you can use in GTM, should be unique to this event
        intouchResponse: response  //optional part, if you need the response in GTM
      })
    }, 
  }
};
```

Please note, you have a typo in your original code (`activa ted` object key with a space in it).

Your GTM trigger will look something like this, in case of an event name from my example:
[image]